# Why does the countdown number color not change when it passes a certain time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a simple countdown to use for sporting. I thought it be fun to create one myself, but I'm stuck on a part I just don't have enough knowledge for..

The countdown is working exactly as I want, but changing the colors + adding a css animation seems like impossible. 
It's about the last part "changeColor"

If you input lets say 60s it will turn green.
Lets say we input 29s, it will turn orange.
if you put in 9s it will turn red.

but why doesn't this change automatically when the seconds change from 30 to 29? It should turn orange then. 
Same goes for 10 > 9s, it should start blinking + turn red, but nothing happens.

See the script below:

```
var CCOUNT;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnct').click(function () {
        CCOUNT = $('#seconds').val();
        cdreset();
    });
});
var t, count;

function cddisplay() {
    document.getElementById('timespan').innerHTML = count;

}

function countdown() {
    // starts countdown
    cddisplay();
    changeColor(CCOUNT);
    if (count === 0) {
        // time is up
    } else {
        count--;
        t = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);

    }
}

function cdpause() {
    // pauses countdown
    clearTimeout(t);
}

function cdreset() {
    // resets countdown
    cdpause();
    count = CCOUNT;
    cddisplay();
}

function changeColor() {
if (CCOUNT <= 1000 && CCOUNT > 30) {
document.getElementById('counting1').style.color = "#00CC00";

}

else if (CCOUNT <= 30 && CCOUNT > 10) {
document.getElementById('timespan').style.color = "#F87217";
}

else {
document.getElementById('timespan').style.color = "#ff0000";
document.getElementById('timespan').css = ({"text-decoration": "blink", "-webkit-animation-name": "0.2s", "text-decoration": "blink", "-webkit-animation-iteration-count": "infinite", "-webkit-animation-timing-function": "ease-in-out", "-webkit-animation-direction": "alternate"});
}
}
```

I've uploaded it to baswijdenes.com/simple-countdown to see it live.

EDIT: I've added the html

```
<center>
<form id="frm">
  <div class="counting">  
    <input type="text" class="input" id="seconds" name="seconds" value="0" size="2" maxlength="4" />    

    </div>
    <input type="button" class="btn blue" id="btnct" value="Input" />

</form>

<div class="counting1" id="counting1">
<span type="text" id="timespan">0</span>
</div>
<BR>
<BR>
<div id="divaroundbuttons">
<input type="button" class="btn green" value="Start" onclick="countdown()">
<input type="button" class="btn orange" value="Stop" onclick="cdpause()">
<input type="button" class="btn red" value="Reset" onclick="cdreset()">
</div>
</center>
```

Comment: When you update the counter, you set the content of an element with id "timespan". The `changeColor()` function, however, sets the color of an element called "counting1".  (Also setting the "css" property of a DOM element will have no effect.)

Comment: That is the div around the timespan, if I use the ID for the timespan it will say it cannot find a property..

Comment: You should post your HTML also. *edit* wait; your `changeColor()` function checks a variable called `CCOUNT`, but the actual counter is the variable `count`.

Comment: Wow, you had that quick! thank you so much :-). I'll see what I can do about the .css property then, I think i'll find that out myself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to debug it and I found that there is two variables that make me confused:

- CCOUNT
- count

When trying to change the function countdown() and adding a console.log(CCOUNT) then I started counting down, I figured out that this variable is not counting down. It's fixed. So I changed CCOUNT with count but here I found that the displayed number changed the color but it's a fixed number.

So I think as a final solution you should count down the two variables CCOUNT and count like this:

```
function countdown() {
    // starts countdown
    cddisplay();
    changeColor(CCOUNT);
    if (CCOUNT=== 0) {
        // time is up
    } else {
        CCOUNT--;
        count--;
        t = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);

    }
}
```

You have another problem with changeColor(). You said that the color should change starting at 29 and 9 seconds not 30 and 10 seconds

I hope this could help

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment :-) Pointy was a few seconds before you with the same answer. Thank you both! I did not see that.